# Fix syntax highlighting for Delphi/Pascal comments

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, syntax-highlighting

In pascal `//` is a comment (which used for a single line). but the syntax highlighting ignores it.

Here is an example:

```pascal
procedure Foo;
begin      
  Bar; // this is a comment that won't highlight

  { 
  this comment highlights as expected 
  ...
  } 

  I := 1;

  (* 
  this comment highlights as expected 
  ...
  *)      
end;
```

The Delphi/Pascal code looks bad when `//` comments are used.
Can this be fixed please?

---

Seems like the same request was already posted back in 2014(!) and was not fixed since:

[Syntax highlighter should support line comments (double slash) for Pascal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341593/937125)

Comment: See the *How do I report a bug or request a new language* section of the FAQ I duped you too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I know "What is syntax highlighting and how does it work"! Nevermind....

Comment: The point is, Stack Overflow uses Google Prettify to handle syntax highlighting, so any bugs in the syntax highlighting need to be reported and fixed there, before they can be reflected on Stack Overflow. Don't get your hopes up on Prettify doing anything. I submitted a pull request months ago for a complete implementation of x86 assembly language highlighting, but no one has paid any attention.

Comment: @CodyGray, *"Stack Overflow uses Google Prettify to handle syntax highlighting..."* - OK, I was not aware of the fact that SO didn't have control over this project (Which is a bit strange?). Thanks for the info.

Comment: Right, I assumed you didn't. It's discussed in the "How does it work?" section of the FAQ answer that Martijn linked you to, but it sounded like you didn't understand how that was relevant, so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @CodyGray, I don't want to sound rude, but isn't it up to SO to report those bugs (and fixing them) instead of relying on SO users to do that? Shouldn't this issue must be under the *control* of SO?